# trying to extract a string from a js this keyword

Tags: javascript, search, this

I'm trying to execute javascript after a link is clicked before loading the link, using this code:

```
$('body').on("click", 'a', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log(this);
            $('.content').addClass('hide');
            if (this.search("AV") > 0) {
                $('#AVheader').addClass('fullwidth');
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.open(this, "_self");
            }, 500);
        });
```

My errors are:

`this.search` Isn't a function and

`window.open(this, "_self");` doesn't work

Wanted to put the question out there since I couldn't find a simple explanation and I'd probably spend half a day trying to figure it out..

Comment: What is `this.search`? Is it a function outside of the code you shared above?

Comment: Where do you want to search for the `AV` string? In the `href`? In the link content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the event handler `this` points to the clicked link. There is no `search` method for an element. Probably you are trying to search for a string somewhere in the link, maybe the content.

```
    $('body').on("click", 'a', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(this);
        $('.content').addClass('hide');
        if (this.innerHTML.search("AV") > 0) {
            $('#AVheader').addClass('fullwidth');
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.open(this.href, "_self");
        }.bind(this), 500);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, I went with
`if (this.href.search("AV") > 0)` to solve the first problem and `window.open(that.href, "_self");` for the second, defining that outside the timeout

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the timeout function will not reference your anchor element, it will instead reference the global `window` object. You will need to save a reference to the element and then use that reference inside the timeout callback

```
$('body').on("click", 'a', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  //save the "this" reference
  var that = this;
  $('.content').addClass('hide');
  if (this.search.search("AV") > 0) {
    $('#AVheader').addClass('fullwidth');
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.open(that.search, "_self");
  }, 500);
});
```

Also `.search` property on the anchor element is not a function it is a string, you would have to do `this.search.search("AV")` or `this.href.search("AV")` depending on what you are actually trying to search on

Comment: Thanks yup defining `var that` made a difference, went with `window.open(that.href, "_self");` to load the link